# How to create instance in Asia Pacific for Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine

How to deploy google app engine App, create instance of Google Cloud SQL in Asia Zone and enable billing for Asia?

Answer (score 0):

For App Engine App you can't specify Asia, only EU (because of their data laws). [Read here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/unleashing-appengine-scalability/).

Cloud SQL when you create the SQL instance you can set the region then.

What do you mean by billing for Asia? Billing is for the project not the region.